# Why is Equals method called before full deserialization of an object?

Tags: c#, dictionary, serialization

I want to serialize and deserialize objects, which are contained in a dictionary, implement `Equals` method and contain dictionaries inside. However it leads to an `ArgumentException`, because `Equals` method is called too early on deserialization.

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using NUnit.Framework;

[Serializable]
public class SerializableObject
{
    public Dictionary<string, bool> Values = new Dictionary<string, bool>();

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is SerializableObject other))
            return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
            return true;
        if (Values.Count != other.Values.Count)
            return false;
        foreach (var (k, v) in Values)
            if (!other.Values.TryGetValue(k, out var otherV) || v != otherV)
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

[Test]
public void DeserializeDictionary()
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var obj1 = new SerializableObject();
        obj1.Values["aaa"] = true;
        var obj2 = new SerializableObject();
        obj2.Values["bbb"] = false;

        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        var dict = new Dictionary<SerializableObject, bool>
        {
            [obj1] = true,
            [obj2] = false
        };

        formatter.Serialize(stream, dict);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        dict = (Dictionary<SerializableObject, bool>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);

        Assert.Contains(obj1, dict.Keys);
        Assert.Contains(obj2, dict.Keys);
    }
}
```

When deserializing, `Equals` method is called on two objects, which have empty dictionaries, and an `ArgumentException` happens ("An item with the same key has already been added").

Also, if the object implements `[OnDeserialized]` method, this method is also called when the dictionary is still empty, and the inner dictionary is filled later, before returning the entire top-level dictionary.

**EDIT**: In this short example `GetHashCode` deliberately returns 0 to force `Equals` to be called. In the real-world program there are just two unequal objects with the same hash code (a collision).

**EDIT 2**: Here is a more complex example where the objects are nested.

```cs
[Serializable]
public class SerializableObject : ISerializable
{
    public SerializableObject() {}

    public Dictionary<string, bool> Values = new Dictionary<string, bool>();

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is SerializableObject other))
            return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
            return true;
        if (Values.Count != other.Values.Count)
            return false;
        foreach (var kvp in Values)
            if (!other.Values.TryGetValue(kvp.Key, out var otherV) || kvp.Value != otherV)
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() => 0;

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) =>
        info.AddValue(nameof(Values), Values.ToArray());

    private SerializableObject(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) =>
        Values = new Dictionary<string, bool>(info.Get<KeyValuePair<string, bool>[]>(nameof(Values)));
}

[Serializable]
public class SerializableObject2 : ISerializable
{
    public SerializableObject2() { }

    public Dictionary<SerializableObject, bool> Values = new Dictionary<SerializableObject, bool>();

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is SerializableObject2 other))
            return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
            return true;
        if (Values.Count != other.Values.Count)
            return false;
        foreach (var kvp in Values)
            if (!other.Values.TryGetValue(kvp.Key, out var otherV) || kvp.Value != otherV)
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() => 0;

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) =>
        info.AddValue(nameof(Values), Values.ToArray());

    private SerializableObject2(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) =>
        Values = new Dictionary<SerializableObject, bool>(info.Get<KeyValuePair<SerializableObject, bool>[]>(nameof(Values)));
}

[Test]
public void DeserializeDictionary()
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var obj1 = new SerializableObject();
        obj1.Values["aaa"] = true;
        var obj2 = new SerializableObject();
        obj2.Values["bbb"] = false;

        var sobj1 = new SerializableObject2
        {
            Values = new Dictionary<SerializableObject, bool>
            {
                [obj1] = true,
                [obj2] = false
            }
        };

        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        formatter.Serialize(stream, sobj1);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        sobj1 = (SerializableObject2)formatter.Deserialize(stream);

        Assert.Contains(obj1, sobj1.Values.Keys);
        Assert.Contains(obj2, sobj1.Values.Keys);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that it will always be called. The problem is that when it is called, the object is not yet constructed, so Values dictionary is EMPTY. So the unequal objects are considered equal because their contents is not yet deserialized!

Comment: Since hash codes does not guaranteed to be stable, dictionary can not store them in serialization stream. Dictionary needs to recalculate hashes after dictionary's keys deserialized. For that it implement `IDeserializationCallback`, which is called after object graph deserialized. I am not sure it there are any documented order in which `IDeserializationCallback` should be called when multiple such objects exists in object graph, but [current implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/serialization/objectmanager.cs,774) combine them in FIFO order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure and am just speculating, but it doesn't look like the `SerializableObject` is being populated until after the `Dictionary` that was serialized (in this case, `dict`) has added them.

It does seem like you can get around the issue by having `SerializableObject` implement `ISerializable` and provide your own `GetObjectData` and Deserialization constructor.

```csharp
[Serializable]
public class SerializableObject : ISerializable
{
  public SerializableObject()
  {
  }

  public Dictionary<string, bool> Values = new Dictionary<string, bool>();

  public override bool Equals(object obj)
  {
     if (!(obj is SerializableObject other))
        return false;
     if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
        return true;
     if (Values.Count != other.Values.Count)
        return false;
     foreach (var kvp in Values)
        if (!other.Values.TryGetValue(kvp.Key, out var otherV) || kvp.Value != otherV)
           return false;
     return true;
  }

  public override int GetHashCode()
  {
     return 0;
  }

  public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
  {
     info.AddValue(KeyValuePairsKey, Values.Select(kvp => kvp).ToArray());
  }

  private SerializableObject(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
  {
     var kvps = info.GetValue(KeyValuePairsKey, typeof(KeyValuePair<string, bool>[])) as KeyValuePair<string, bool>[];
     foreach (var kvp in kvps)
     {
        Values.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
     }
  }

  private const string KeyValuePairsKey = "KVPS";
}

class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
     {

        var obj1 = new SerializableObject();
        obj1.Values["aaa"] = true;
        var obj2 = new SerializableObject();
        obj2.Values["bbb"] = false;

        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        var dict = new Dictionary<SerializableObject, bool>
        {
           [obj1] = true,
           [obj2] = false
        };

        formatter.Serialize(stream, dict);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        dict = (Dictionary<SerializableObject, bool>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works. The code of deserialization constructor can even be simplified:
`Values = new Dictionary<string, bool>((KeyValuePair<string, bool>[])info.GetValue(KeyValuePairsKey, typeof(KeyValuePair<string, bool>[])));`

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution doesn’t work if the objects are nested. I’ve added a more complex example which fails with a `NullReferenceException` because the deserialization constructor of outer object is called before creating the inner object.

Answer (score 0):

You always return 0 in the method GetHashCode(). I think the dictionary uses the GetHashCode() to determine the equality of keys.

Comment: No, hash code is never the only source of equality. If hash codes are different, then the objects are definitely different, and `Equals` method is not called. If hash codes are equal, then either the objects are equal, or there is a hash collision, so `Equals` method is called to distinguish these cases. Before serialization, the dictionary contains both objects, so they are not considered equal.

Comment: Really bad practice, but you could delegate GetHashCode to Values.GetHashCode. Really bad practice because Values can mutate.

Comment: This way all objects would have quasi-different hash codes, so even equal objects would be considered unequal when putting them to a collection. Hash code 0 is correct, though bad for performance, and your suggestion is violates correctness.